# Intellij idea not recognizing mochajs keywords like 'describe', beforeAll, it, etc

Tags: javascript, selenium, intellij-idea, mocha.js

I am just setting up a small learning project using mochajs in Intellij Idea.  I can run a simple test successfully but Intellij idea does not seem to recognize keywords 'describe', 'beforeAll', 'it'..etc.  How can i fix this?

[image]

```
{
  "name": "seleniumjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --no-timeout ./tests/*.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocha doesn't expose its globals, so the only way to get these methods recognized by static code analysys is installing typings (`npm i @types/mocha`).

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files